# Can we use javascript files in existing project built using typescript (ts,tsx)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-query

I was assigned a task to add some pages to the existing project that is build using
`Laravel: 8.12`
`React: 17.0.2`
`NextJS: 10.0.9`
`Tailwind CSS: 2.0.4`
`React Query: 3.13.0 [ REST]`
`TypeScript: 4.2.3`

The problem is that i dont know if I can add javascript files in the codebase, if it is possible what changes do I need to make it  to work both typescript and javascript?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. You can either disable some typescript features to it becomes backwards compatible with javascript, or add `.d` files to annotate the types of the javascript library

Comment: .d with js files?

Comment: Typescript declaration files* most importantly you should set allowJs to true inside your tsconfig

Comment: ok thats already set to true...what next?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/calling-java-script-from-type-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` file you need to add the `--allowJs` [flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#allowJs) in order to have both JavaScript and TypeScript files in the same codebase.

Comment: that already true....now can i proceed with this setting?

Comment: Now import the JavaScript file into your project and see if it is compiled. If you do not receive any errors and you can access the code from it, then you should be good to go.